# how to solve array_walk error

Tags: php, arrays

This is my codes and I got an error:

```
  require_once(IPT_DIR."config.php");
    if ($trackip == 1) {
            $ipaddr = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] ;
     $hostnm = gethostbyaddr("$ipaddr");

     $exclude_me=false;
     array_walk($exclude_ips, 'exclude_ip');
     if(!$exclude_me) array_walk($exclude_hosts, 'exclude_host');
     if (!$exclude_me) {
      # concatenate SCRIPT_NAME and QUERY_STRING since REQUEST_URI not used in Windows hosted sites.
      # $pg = getenv(REQUEST_URI);
      # $pg = getenv(SCRIPT_NAME);
      $pg = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"];
      # if ((getenv(QUERY_STRING)) != "") { $pg = $pg . "?" . getenv(QUERY_STRING) ; }
      if (($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]) != "") { $pg = $pg . "?" . $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] ; }

    }
```

And the *config.php* file:

```
$trackip = 1;

$exclude_ips = array(); # quoted IP comma separated list, wildcards ok
# example: $exclude_ips = array('127.0.0.1', '68.69.+');

$exclude_hosts = array(); # quoted Hostname comma separated list, wildcards ok
# example: $exclude_hosts = array('swbcs007.sbc.com', '.+avantgo.com');
```

And when I run this script I get this error:

> Warning: array_walk()
>   [function.array-walk]: The argument
>   should be an array in tracking.php on
>   line 80
>
> Warning: array_walk()
>   [function.array-walk]: The argument
>   should be an array in tracking.php on
>   line 81

Do you know why it’s happening?

Comment: What is output if you `var_dump($exclude_ips);` ?

Answer (score 0):

`$exclude_ips` and `$exclude_hosts` are either not defined, or not arrays. Possible causes:

- You are editing/including the wrong config file (or, less likely, the config file is not included at all, but that should raise an error I believe)
- You are overwriting the arrays from the config file somewhere else before using them in `array_walk`

Comment: so what is ur suggestion , and what should i do exactly , i should note that when i remove require config.php line  , everything goes fine , but im sure that would be disabling the functionality

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following - in config.php and tracking.php just before using $exclude_ips  and $exclude_hosts add

```
global $exclude_hosts;
global $exclude_ips;
```